# How do I put EMACS local variables into a HTML file?

Tags: emacs

GNU Emacs [Local Variables](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_486.html) make it possible to enable or disable modes automatically when a file is opened. I'm interested in disabling auto-fill mode when I open .HTML files. I want to use Local Variables because I want the effects on a single file, not on all of my .HTML text files. (Otherwise, I would have put it in my .emacs file).  I also want other, per-file actions.

The trouble with using existing Local Variables examples is that they are all based on putting comments at the beginning of a file, but HTML files can't have comments at the beginning.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to disable auto-fill when you "open .HTML files" or do you want to use "Local Variables" (i.e. do it for one particular file)?  Normally "Local Variables" are used for settings which are inherently specific to the contents of this particular file, rather than for personal preferences that apply to all files of this format, so in most cases `auto-fill-mode` is better set in one's `~/.emacs` rather than in "Local Variables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like:

```
<!--
  Local Variables:
  eval: (auto-fill-mode -1)
  End:
  -->
```

near the end of your file.

Comment: Oh, that's right — Local variables can go at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the best way to do it depends on how/why auto-fill mode is enabled when you open an html file (by default, it's not the case, so it's due to a local config of yours).

But my best guess is that I'd do something like:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
          (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))
```

tho it depends also which mode you're using for html files.  It could be a mode derived from nxml-mode or from sgml-mode, so you could also try

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook
          (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))
```

or

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook
          (lambda () (auto-fill-mode -1)))
```

Comment: But I want to do it with a Local Variables, not with the config file...